# rake db:create - getting a syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

thank you everyone for helping me out with this.  i am new to ruby on rails

here is my database.yml file::

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# 

Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql
# On Mac 

OS X:
#   sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-

dir=/usr/local/mysql
# On Mac OS X Leopard:
#   sudo env 

ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-

mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
#       

This sets the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to your 

native architecture
# On Windows:
#   gem install mysql
#   

    Choose the win32 build.
#       Install MySQL and put 

its /bin directory on your path.
#
# And be sure to use 

new-style password hashing:
#   

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: 

blog_development
 pool: 5 username: root
  password:


socket: /tmp/mysql.sock host: localhost

# Warning: The 

database defined as 'test' will be erased and
# re-

generated from your development database when you run 

'rake'.
# Do not set this db to the same as development 

or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8


database: blog_test
  username: root
  password:
  host: 

localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8


database: blog_production
  username: root
  password: 


host: localhost
```

when i do a `rake db:create`

i am getting this error:

```
syntax error on line 20 col 1: ' pool: 5 username: root'
```

thank you again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that read:

```
pool: 5
username: root
```

... on separate lines?